# Como poner un TextView encima de un color, sin que afecte tanto el color por el margen del < TextView>

Tags: android-studio, xml

Estoy tratando de crear una pantalla en la que tengo 2 colores para el background, el problema es cuando quiero poner un < TextView> encima de un background, en la que parte del background es afectado por el área del < TextView>
[image: Este es el resultado]

La idea es que alrededor del < TextView> no tenga ese fondo gris, alguna solución o consejo.

Este es mi código:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_redondo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tu_app_de_viajes"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes definir un `background`, pero al usar   `MaterialTextView`  lo ideal es definir un `shape` que defina el color del fondo, crea el siguiente archivo `fondo_textview.xml` en el directorio `/drawable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#663366"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

En tu vista define el .xml como fondo y un color de texto usando `textColor` :

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tu_app_de_viajes"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"

    android:background="@drawable/fondo_textview.xml"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```